# How to pass the achor text innerHtml in javascript

Tags: javascript, text, anchor, innerhtml

I have an anchor text link that contains information that I need to parse:

```
<a href="javascript:parselink(this)">
    <div class="calendar">
        <div class='day'>8</div>
        <div class="number">75</div>
    </div>
</a>

  <script>
    function parselink(link){
        alert(link.innerHtml);
    }
  </script>
```

However, I am not able to get the anchor text's innerHhtml.

Comment: And what is desired output? innerHTML will return HTML of child elements, not sure that you need it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo

```
innerHtml !== innerHTML
```

And use onclick, not href to trigger the event

```js
    function parselink(link){ 
        alert(link.innerHTML);
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="parselink(this); return false;">
    <div class="calendar">
        <div class='day'>8</div>
        <div class="number">75</div>
    </div>
</a>
```